# conditional format each column separately

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a table that looks like this.

```
GameName    Impressions        Downloads
GameNum1    150000             300
GameNum2    25000              400
GameNum3    50000              20
```

I want to conditionally format each column separately with a color range so I can easily see which game is getting the most impressions and downloads. Right now, if I use a conditional formatting rule it groups both numbers together. For example, since Impressions is always higher than Downloads, everything in the impressions column is green, and everything in the Downloads column is red.

In order to do this, I have to apply a new conditional formatting rule on each column. Of course with just two columns I can manually do this, but in reality I have many columns so this is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what conditional formatting you want. Say based on the small example above, what formatting do you expect exactly.

Comment: I would expect for Impressions - GameNum1 is green, GameNum2 is red, and GameNum3 is neutral. For Downloads, GameNum1 is green-ish, GameNum2 is Green, and GameNum3 is red.

Comment: Have you succeeded to make a conditional format as you want it - with color ranges applied correctly - for just one column on its own - say "downloads".

Comment: What format do you expect ? As far as I know, you can always format a column. What is your format formula ? If your format group both number together, it means you are using a wrong formula.

Comment: Yes I can definitely conditionally format one column with a color range. In Google Sheets I go Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Color Scale. @HaPhan I want to format the background color of the cell.

Answer (score -1):

In this specific case, because "Impressions" is always higher than "Downloads", you can put 2 conditional formats for the values of the two column : if cell higher than a minimum value of "Impressions", format it with some color. This will color the "Impressions" column. If the cell is lesser than that value, then it is the "Downloads" column, format it with other color. This will color the "Downloads" column. Refer to [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PmppyO7SF9A2fxfTDeun34tO-vZouB3c8Fgp9N0EJ6s/edit?usp=sharing) for your case..

The >1 is to tell the format to leave empty cells alone. The `Istext` is to tell the format to leave the column header alone.

One other way to format columns differently is to use this formula: `=MOD(COLUMN(A1),2)=0`. This formula makes use of the odd / even number of column : If column is odd, format with this color. If even, format it with other color. This is done with the 3rd condition formula in the sample sheet.